# How to package custom lessc into django project? (using django-pipeline)

Tags: django, less

I want to use `django-pipeline` to compile my `LESS` files into a single `CSS` file. 
I want `django-pipeline` to use the `lessc` that I have bundled into a /bin/ directory that is in my django project. I am trying to correctly set: `PIPELINE_LESS_BINARY` in order to do this correctly, except `django-pipeline` runs the command from the `source_filenames` directory it appears.

How can set the path to my custom compiler correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this, and adapt it to your directory structure :

```
import os
local_path = lambda path: os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), path)

PIPELINE_LESS_BINARY = local_path('bin/lessc')
```

`local_path` return the path of a file relatively to the `settings.py` file path.

Comment: I tried this orginially but that gives me a different issue. lessc is a javascript file that needs node, which is also in my django project. So now I'm having trouble correctly setting "bin/node" in lessc

Comment: It's more a configuration issue between node/npm and lessc so, but this setup is still relevant. Try install lessc via ``npm -g install lessc``

Comment: So this might just be a flaw wit the project setup, but I was hoping to have a mostly self sustained django project with virtualenv. Is something like this still possible? Wouldn't npm require that node be installed on the machine and not have an automatic way to manage that dependency?

Comment: ``lessc`` is not written in Python, so ``virtualenv`` is irrelevant.